# Why the redis cluster just created used_memory_human is about 200M?

Tags: redis

Why the redis cluster just created `used_memory_human` is about 200M?

```
# Memory
used_memory:236472968
used_memory_human:225.52M
used_memory_rss:5402624
used_memory_rss_human:5.15M
used_memory_peak:236541944
used_memory_peak_human:225.58M
used_memory_peak_perc:99.97%
used_memory_overhead:236392512
used_memory_startup:1444912
used_memory_dataset:80456
used_memory_dataset_perc:0.03%
```

Comment: Perhaps you're loading some data from disk?

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your setup?